# Get data within the current hour in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

The following will bring data from start of day to end of day :

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [ Carbon::now()->startOfDay(),Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])
```

Is there a way to bring data from the start of the current hour to end of current hour ? And will it include today's date as well, just to make sure it doesn't get data within this hour but in all days ?

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-modifiers - There is `startofHour` and `endOfHour`. It does that one date, though. If you want to get it for every day, you might want to use the MySQL `HOUR()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you just add 1 hour to now?

```php
->whereBetween('created_at', [
             now()->format('Y-m-d H:00:00'),
             now()->addHours(1)->format('Y-m-d H:00:00')
]);
```

## Example:

`routes/web.php`

```php
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    $users = factory(App\User::class, 25)->create();
    foreach ($users->take(10) as $user) {
        $user->created_at = now()->addDay();
        $user->save();
    }
    return App\User::whereBetween('created_at', [
        now()->format('Y-m-d H:00:00'),
        now()->addHours(1)->format('Y-m-d H:00:00')
    ])->count();
});
```

## Results:

15
Only users within this hour of **TODAY** are returned